# Rails - render partial collection as not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a partial of a collection using a name different to that of the model:

```
<%= render "current_campaigns", collection: @current_campaigns, as: :current_campaign %>
```

The model is called Campaign but this is a subset of campaigns as defined in the controller action:

```
def index
  @current_campaigns = Campaign.where(status: :approved)
end
```

In the partial (which lives in the application directory not the campaigns directory):

```
<%= current_campaign.question %>
```

The resulting error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_campaign' for #<#<Class:0x007fad3d5e5500>:0x007fad451976a8>
```

I was under the impression that `as` would make this work but apparently not. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you show "current_campaigns" template?

Comment: @ilgam the partial currently only contains what I've put above: 
`<%= current_campaign.question %>`

The file name of the partial is: 
`_current_campaigns.html.erb`

Comment: @danny_santos what is the name of the directory where the file is?

Comment: @ilgam Ah I should have mentioned that thanks, it's in the application directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

`<%= render partial: 'path-relative-to-views/current_campaigns', collection: @current_campaigns, as: :current_campaign %>`

And the partial should name `_current_campaign.html.erb` for convention.

Comment: That's the one! Seems the keyword "partial" was pretty important there, although it's worth noting that the relative file path wasn't a necessity. Thanks for the solution, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename campaigns/current_campaigns.html.erb template to campaigns/campaign.html.erb and render like that from campaigns/:

```
<%= render @current_campaigns %>
```

Otherwise you can specify name of directory where the partial is:

```
<%= render "other_folder_name/campaign", collection: @current_campaigns %>
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. I should probably point out that the partial is in the application directory, not the campaign directory

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to pass attributes to the partial using a custom name is:

```
<%= render "current_campaigns", custom_name: @current_campaigns %>
```

doing this you will be able to use custom_name as a defined variable on your partial.

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference in my case, I'm still getting the undefined method error